# Spotify facebook login

Tags: facebook, spotify

[image]

As you can see on the image, spotify has a modified version of facebook login.

On the spotify app shown, user can login using either facebook or spotify account.

I wonder if its only on the looks or they were using other facebook authentication process.

I also wonder and worried if spotify could get facebook password entered by the user.

What facebook authentication they were using in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, Spotify is using a different Facebook login flow that is not listed anywhere in the official Facebook developer documentation. Since the Facebook password is entered into a closed source client, there is no way for you to know for sure what happens without heavy reverse engineering and debugging of the client. In that sense you should be worried. It goes against and devalues the good policy of "Please don't enter your password anywhere else". Thinking about differently, Facebook trusts this company enough to allow this. There might be a few more companies that have the ability to use this login flow, but I don't know.

I work at Spotify and was there when it was introduced (September 2011). We worked very closely with Facebook (I helped build some parts of the backend integration). It is not my favorite part of the client though. I would much prefer a standard Facebook OAuth 2 authorization flow. That was however one of the main technical problems in spring 2011 when we started to build this. We basically needed to embed a browser in the client to make it work properly or redirect the user to a browser and then back to the client again. There were also other reasons that I can't remember why we didn't do this.

Now when we have an embedded browser (since December 2011) it would be much easier to change. I believe this type of login flow will be phased out eventually.

Comment: thanks @jooon, spotify app is good and fast in loading music.